# Wordpress add_image_size

Tags: wordpress, crop, image-size

I am struggling to get Wordpress to properly crop a photo based on a custom add_image_size I've setup. I want the crop to be left, top but it keeps cropping in the what seems like the wrong place to me. What am I missing?

**Here's the PHP:**

```
add_image_size ('resorts-accordion', 225, 340, array( 'left', 'top', true ) );
```

Original Image:

[image]

Wrongly Cropped Image:

[image]

Intended crop:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the `true` value in the crop array? The array is supposed to only have two values.

Comment: Note that your intended crop will most probably not be possible with this function, since your intended crop cuts off part on the left. You can only crop on the left, right, top, bottom and center.

Comment: I have tried removing true. No dice. My understanding of left top or left center is it will start the crop far left and crop to the stated width toward the center. This article lays it out in detail. [link]https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/wordpress-thumbnail-crop[link] Wordpress actually links to this article from the codex. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the crop array accepts only 2 values. Read more [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/#crop-mode).
Also check [this post](https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/wordpress-thumbnail-crop) about the wp crop modes.

Test it like this:

```
add_image_size('resorts-accordion', 225, 340, array( 'left', 'top' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried removing the true statement and get the same thing. And that article is AWESOME! I've been referencing it. But even when I apply how she lays it out I don't get the same result. Maybe delete all versions of that image, reset the function and go again?!

Answer (score -1):

And here is the image the way I want it to actually crop:

[How I want the image to actually crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cutrK.jpg)

Comment: Please edit additions into your question, don't post them as an answer.

Comment: They won't let me post more than two images in my question so had to post it here.